# Laravel 4 Eloquent: multiple relationship methods referencing the same model?

Tags: php, orm, laravel-4

I have DB tables as follows:

```
images:
id name url etc

places:
id image_id name url etc

image_place:
image_id place_id
```

Places and images have a many-to-many relationship, but each place is also assigned a single image, which is used as the thumbnail in lists. So a place may "belong to" an image in a one-to-many relationship. Therefore I tried this in Laravel 4:

models/Place.php:

```
public function image() {
  return $this->belongsTo('Image');
}
public function images() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Image');
}
```

But when I try to access $place->image, I get an error: "call to unknown method getResults()."

I've done some experimenting and found these workarounds:

1. If I remove the images() method, $place->image works as expected. I don't use images() currently, so this is my solution for now, but certainly I would like to have both available.
2. If I replace the image() function with: return Image::where('id', $this->image_id)->first(); then I can access the object via $place->image(). But I can't do eager loading, which is important since I use the thumbnails in long lists of results. Plus I don't like having to use the method() syntax for just this one property.

I also tried renaming the methods, e.g. image() and photos(), but it made no difference.

Is accessing the same model with different types of relationships not possible in Laravel, or am I missing something?

Comment: Your `images()` should be `hasMany`, you have it as `belongsToMany`.

Comment: I think a Place "has one" Image here, not the opposite.

Comment: Sajan: See my comment to your answer. @matpop, I don't think so, because: 1. "hasOne" is only used in one-to-one relationships in the docs. 2. image() is currently working as expected with belongsTo. 3. It's parallel to the example in the docs under One to Many (http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships): just as a post has many comments, an image may have many (= be the thumbnail for many) places. In the example, the comments table has a post_id column and belongsTo a Post, and my places table has an image_id column and belongsTo an Image.

Answer (score 1):

Your `images()` should be `hasMany`, you have it as `belongsToMany`.  I am assuming you've properly built your database schema.

*Assumptions*

places table has column `image_id` for the single image you use.

images table has column `place_id` for the place the image is associated with.

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Image');
}

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Image');
}
```

Comment: I am using belongsToMany because it is a many-to-many relationship, as you can see from my third table, "image_place." See the docs at http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships: "We can define a many-to-many relation using the belongsToMany method." And your second assumption is not correct. One image may have many places (places can refer to sites and buildings, so think of a photo of a city skyline, which includes a lot of skyscrapers).